# MongoDB find if none of the items in mongo array are not in python list

Tags: python, mongodb

I have did some research but couldn't make it: what is the correct MongoDB query using `pymongo` to find documents only if none of items in MongoDB array field are not in a python list?

Something like:

```
python3
blocked_firms = ["firma", "firmb", "firmc"]
cur = DB.tweets.find({
    "firm": {"$nin": blocked_firms}
}, {"text": 1, "_id": 0})
```

So find all items that none of the firms in `blocked_firms` is equal to any item in `firm` field in MongoDB documents.`firm` field in MongoDB is an array field.

The `python` equivalent would be:

```
python3
In [2]: l1 = ["a", "b"]                                                                                                                                                                                            
In [3]: l2 = ["b", "c"]                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [4]: any([i in l2 for i in l1])                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[4]: True

In [5]: l3 = ["d", "c"]

In [6]: any([item in l3 for item in l1])                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[6]: False
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Show sample documents and the result you expect. Also quoting the documentation for [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)- *"the field value is not in the specified array or
the field does not exist."* At a guess, it's probably that second clause that is throwing you, so `{ "firm": { "$nin": blocked_items, "$exists": True } }` is typically what people really mean here.

Comment: The thing is, `firm` field is also an array here. So it's a list-list comparison. How `$nin` would work here? Isn't it meant to check an individual item is whether in a list or not, instead of checking like I did in python equivalent in the question?

Comment: In short, MongoDB does not really care. Yes there is a very common misconception that operators like `$in` or `$nin` are **needed** when *comparing to an array*, where the actual implementation is a *list of arguments to compare*, but what it actually compares against can either be a singular property or indeed vales within an array. It **does matter** in the case where you asked for **every** array element to either match or not match the list supplied.  However in a simple case of "do not select documents with things in this list", then it pretty much works as designed.

Comment: In *super short*, if you think there is a case where your list of `["firma", "firmb", "firmc"]` is not returning what you think it should, then show specific document examples of what matches and what you think should match. Your question only goes *"half way"* as you show code you attempted, and then walk off into a completely unrelated sample of other code which has nothing to do with the data you should be matching as shown in the initial statement. So the question could be better, if even needed at all.

Comment: Thanks to point out. I actually tried `$nin`for my situation and unexpectedly (at least from my point) it did what I want.